# Raspberry Pi OS Google 2FA over SSH Keeps Asking For The Password and OTP

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi, 2-factor-authentication

I followed this guide: https://pimylifeup.com/setup-2fa-ssh/ however this is what I get when trying to connect (it is stuck in a loop and keeps asking for the password and key):

```
ssh jacob@192.168.4.141                                
(jacob@192.168.4.141) Password: 
(jacob@192.168.4.141) Verification code: 
(jacob@192.168.4.141) Password: 
(jacob@192.168.4.141) Verification code: 
(jacob@192.168.4.141) Password: 
(jacob@192.168.4.141) Verification code: 
jacob@192.168.4.141's password:
```

This happens if the code is right or wrong, it doesn't matter ether way.
If the password is wrong, it will ask for it again (no verification code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also encountered this.

I fixed it by not running:

```
sudo google-authenticator
```

Make sure you are logged into the user you want for ssh, and just run:

```
google-authenticator
```

The hint came from this line:

"Do you want me to update your "/root/.google_authenticator" file? (y/n)"

which should have said:

"Do you want me to update your "/home/[your user]/.google_authenticator" file? (y/n)"